# Lightning Lint tool doesn't like Object.values() method: is there any workaround?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-lint-tool

I see the following Lightning Lint tool error in my project

```
 error  ecma-intrinsics  Invalid Intrinsic API                
  Line:31:30
              selectedRecords: Object.values( component.get('v.selectedRecordsMap') ),
                                ^
```

I have read [this documentation article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules_ecma_intrinsic.htm)

> Validate JavaScript Intrinsic APIs (ecma-intrinsics) This rule deals
>   with the intrinsic APIs in JavaScript, more formally known as
>   ECMAScript. When LockerService is enabled, the framework prevents the
>   use of unsupported API objects or calls. That means your Lightning
>   components code is allowed to use: Features built into JavaScript
>   (“intrinsic” features) Published, supported features built into the
>   Lightning Component framework Published, supported features built into
>   LockerService SecureObject objects What exactly are these “intrinsic
>   APIs”? They’re the APIs defined in the ECMAScript Language
>   Specification. That is, things built into JavaScript. This includes
>   Annex B of the specification, which deals with legacy browser features
>   that aren’t part of the “core” of JavaScript, but are nevertheless
>   still supported for JavaScript running inside a web browser.
>
> Note that some features of JavaScript that you might consider
>   intrinsic—for example, the window and document global variables—are
>   superceded by SecureObject objects, which offer a more constrained
>   API.
>
> Rule Details This rule verifies that use of the intrinsic JavaScript
>   APIs is according to the published specification. The use of
>   non-standard, deprecated, and removed language features is disallowed.

I have looked through the related documents but still I don't understand what is wrong with getting values list from map using Object.values() method?

Is there any way to avoid this lint error?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to avoid this error? even I'm getting a similar error.

Comment: No, I just give up, maybe, I would return to this later

Answer (score 2):

Lightning supports the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) specification. `Object.values` was introduced in ECMAScript 2017:

[image: Object.values Specification History]

**References**

- [Object.values() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [proposal-object-values-entries/polyfill.js at master · tc39/proposal-object-values-entries · GitHub](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js)
- [Explore New Syntax in JavaScript ES6 Unit | Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/explore-new-syntax-in-javascript-es6)
- [Get Started with Modern JavaScript Development Unit | Salesforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/modern-javascript-development/get-started-with-modern-javascript-development)
- [Lightning Experience Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&type=5)
- [Enable Lightning Component Developers to Use TypeScript and EcmaScript 6 - Ideas - Salesforce Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CPrdQAG)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to avoid this lint error?

There is. You could not use `Object.values` as it is, essentially, a syntactic sugar for an `Object.keys` with a `.map`. You are able to replace it with:

```js
var obj = {name: "Robert"};

// returns an 'Array [ "Robert" ]' object.
Object.values();

// same but without .values
Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });
```

Just be careful to check if the object you are using is not *falsy*. If it is, say, `undefined`, you'll get a TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object